# How to troubleshoot "We couldn’t find a run python"?

Tags: python-3.x, zapier

I'm working on a pre-existing python code-by-zapier zap. The trigger is "Code By Zapier; Run Python". I've made some changes to the contained python script, and now when I go to test that step I run into the following error message:

> #### We couldn’t find a run python
>
> Create a new run python in your Code by Zapier account and test your trigger again.

Is there any way of figuring out what went wrong?

Comment: Did you follow the hint and make sure you have a python run time available in your Code by Zapier account? Perhaps you should work through some of simple examples first to make sure you've reached the 'hello world' stage

Comment: So far as I'm aware that's not really how Zapier works. The zap in question that I'm trying to test is a previously working zap. The error message is _confusing_ because what I have is an account with Zapier; "Code by Zapier" is a configurable widget _within Zapier_. The use of "run python" as a noun is consistent with the rest of the app, except that _the thing that I'm trying to test is_ a "run python", so it's a bit nonsensical for the app to complain that it can't find the thing it just failed to run. (Yes I reloaded the page to make sure the zap in question actually exists.)

Comment: Oh, I played with their sandpit, to manipulate a google sheet, and when I went to test it, it 'found' a 'run python' (a pyhton runtime). So for you it was working, then you make changes to the code and it stops working? I'm not to tell you how to troubleshoot, but when confronted by weirdness, I like to backtrace (as in reverse changes) until I have something that works, and then add back the changes.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing a little bit, but I think this issue stems from repeatedly testing an existing trigger without returning a new ID.

When you run a test (or click the "load more" button), then Zapier runs the trigger and looks through the array for any new items it hasn't seen before. It bases "newness" on whether it recognizes the `id` field in each returned object.

So if you're testing code that changed, but is returning objects with previously seen `id`s, then the editor will error saying that it can't find any new objects (the `can't find new run pythons` is a quirk of the way that text is generated; think of it as "can't find objects that we haven't seen before).

The best way to fix this depends on if you're returning an `id` and if you need it for something.

- Your code can return a random id. This means every returned item will trigger a Zap every time, which may or may not be intended behavior.
- You can *probably* copy your code, change the trigger app (to basically anything else), run a successful test (which will overwrite your old test data), and then change it back to `Code by Zapier` and paste your code. Then you should get a "fresh" test. Due to changes in the way sample data is stored, I'm not positive this works now
- Duplicate the zap from the "My Zaps" page. The new one won't have any existing sample data, so you should be able to test normally.